# Don't call ViewHolder on Adapter (RecycleView)

Tags: android, adapter

In my fragment (`OnCreateView`) call adapter to my recView.

```
     recView = (RecyclerView)root.findViewById(R.id.recView);

     adapter = new CustomListAdapter(PokemonValues.pokemonList);

    recView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And Adapter receives values, but dont print.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomListAdapter.pokemonViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Pokemon> datos;

public static class pokemonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView tvMaxCp;
    private TextView tvPokemon;

    public pokemonViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvMaxCp = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMaxCP);
        tvPokemon = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPokemon);
    }

    public void bindTitular(Pokemon t) {
        tvPokemon.setText(t.getCandyEvolve());
        tvMaxCp.setText(t.getMaxCP());
    }


}


public CustomListAdapter(ArrayList<Pokemon> datos) {
    this.datos = datos;
}

@Override
public pokemonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.listview_custom, viewGroup, false);

    pokemonViewHolder tvh = new pokemonViewHolder(itemView);

    return tvh;
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(pokemonViewHolder viewHolder, int pos) {
    Pokemon item = datos.get(pos);

    viewHolder.bindTitular(item);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return datos.size();
}
```

I was debbuging but don't enter into `pokemonViewHolder` class. I forget some method?

I have another adapters like this and work fine.

Thanks

Comment: datos may be empty. No data means no ViewHolder gets created. The code seems basically correct

Comment: CustomListAdapter constructor work, I debugged and work receives the list

Comment: Add a break point here: recView.setAdapter(adapter); and check if getItemCount() returns the desired number of items.

Comment: Add this: recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX Work! Can you explain why?

Comment: @ArisGuimerá "A LayoutManager is responsible for measuring and positioning item views within a RecyclerView as well as determining the policy for when to recycle item views that are no longer visible to the user. By changing the LayoutManager a RecyclerView can be used to implement a standard vertically scrolling list, a uniform grid, staggered grids, horizontally scrolling collections and more. Several stock layout managers are provided for general use."

So all in all: You had the data, but the recyclerview did not know how to "manage" it.